# Accessing the property of a component from child component

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I am trying to access to a custom property of a component from its child component. I get undefined value. My components are..

AppComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: '<star isClicked="false"></star>',    
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

StarComponent:

```
import { Component,Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'star',
  template: `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" 
  [class.glyphicon-star]="isClicked" 
  [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isClicked" 
  on-click="onClick()" >`     
})

export class StarComponent {

  @Input() isClicked;

  constructor(){
      console.log(this.isClicked);
  }

  onClick($event){
     this.isClicked = !this.isClicked;
  }

}
```

I get `undefined` message from chrome console. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Input values are first available in `ngOnChanges`, code in constructor is fired before that. Move your console log to OnInit and it will work :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45219702/6294072

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble passing and accessing data to stateless component in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219529/trouble-passing-and-accessing-data-to-stateless-component-in-angular)

Comment: Ok i can see it on ngOnInit. However, i am expecting  the class to change between glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty and glyphicon glyphicon-star, but doesnt happen when i switch between isClicked="false" and isClicked="true" . Should i ask another qustion about this one ? @AJT_82

Comment: Hmm... works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6JQDZ5xH5PNET2WrvWsu?p=preview btw, changed click event to angularish: `(click)` and there is no `$event` parameter in your click event :)